# CMTimeMake - get smaller / more dissolved values than seconds

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, core-media

I am successfully making a **CMTime** with following code:

```
endPoint = CMTimeMake([mp currentPlaybackTime], 1);
```

The current position, which originally was a float value, of the movie in my MPMoviePlayerController is given back as a CMTime in seconds, which is not bad.

But how I can get this position in e.g. in milli seconds?
I played with the 'timescale' and set it to 10 and 100, but it didn't have an effect to the result.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’m not really sure what you want. Do you understand the logic behind `CMTime`?

```
1.0s = 1/1s  = CMTimeMake(1, 1)
0.1s = 1/10s = CMTimeMake(1, 10)
0.2s = 1/5s  = CMTimeMake(1, 5)
0.2s = 2/10s = CMTimeMake(2, 10)
…
```

In other words, `CMTimeMake(a, b)` is the time value `a/b`. Thus when you have a floating-point time value:

```
double time1 = 0.2;
// in ms, (0.2*1000)/1000 == 200/1000 == 0.2
CMTime time2 = CMTimeMake(time1*1000, 1000);
```

Maybe this is what you want?

Comment: Ah, ok. Know I understand this. I was just confused because did put the value of the CMTime in a NSLog to see them and they every time where integer. Thank you very much !